# Lan network website using google Analytics

Tags: c#, google-analytics

we have inner website (not on the wan network) , we using this website on our company, 
   but we have route to to wan network . 
   can google Analytics can track this website?
   im getting "Tracking Not Installed" and it not track nothing .

Comment: nope, don't think so. AFAIK you need to be connect to the internet and google does not release any of its services as software products you could use.

Comment: Try piwik (http://piwik.org/). You can host it on the server itself.. and it has almost everything that google provides. And it is open source too..

Comment: we connected to the internet "we have route to wan" but the website hosted on our inner servers

Comment: then you have to make sure the google analytics js can ping whereever it needs to..

Answer (score 1):

If you can load the URLs `http://google-analytics.com/ga.js` and `http://google-analytics.com/__utm.gif` from within your LAN network inner website (ie, access the outside, open internet), then Google Analytics will work without a problem.

@Giddy is also incorrect about Google not releasing any of its services as software products, as Google sells [Urchin](http://www.google.com/urchin/index.html), a self-hosted software of which Google Analytics can be considered a fork.

All you need for Google Analytics to work is to send a particularly formatted request to their `__utm.gif` image.

However, if Google Analytics can't crawl the page, it would initially give you a "Tracking Not Installed" Error, since it can't find the website. But, this feature is optional, and is not directly connected to any significant feature working. It's just there to make setup easy for most websites.

Make sure you adjust the date range to include today, as by default, Google Analytics sets its time range exclude today.