# Do i need a running website over internet in order to access Google analytics Data using Google API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api

I am new to Google analytics API. I want to access my Google Analytics Data using its API.I have a local website which is deployed on IIS over a LAN.Using this setup can i access google analytics data by using its API or i need a website running over the internet.If yes please suggest how can it be done using javascript.

Comment: Try the suggestion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579369/lan-network-website-using-google-analytics to see if it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics works by sending information to Google servers whenever someone visits your HTML page (doesn't need to be on the web). However you need access to the internet to send data to the Google servers. You can track any "website" if you make an account on Google Analytics and simply add the code below to whichever page you wish to track (before the `</head>` tag, as Google says):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'TrackingID']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

The `TrackingID` must be replaced by the tracking ID for your Google Analytics account.

Comment: :- Thanks for your answer but i want to access the Google Analytics data using Google API.Could You please tell how it can be doneI.I have checked one code example from developers.google.com but its not working for me..

Comment: What I said is about configuring your website to work with Google Analytics. Regarding the use of Google API, I am not familiar with it, sorry...